# "Gotten" versus "got"

Tags: american-english, past-participles, present-perfect, dialect

When in a sentence I want to use the present perfect of *get*, I say *have/has gotten*.
A friend of mine (who is American) corrects me, saying I should use *have/has got*. From my English classes, I remember that the past participle of *get* is *gotten*.

Why does my friend tell me that it is not correct to use *have gotten*?

If that makes any difference, my friend lives on the east coast, closer to the New England zone.

Comment: I tagged the question with [tag:american-english] since my friend is American, and the question is probably about a difference between American English, and British English (which is the English dialect I was taught in my English classes).

Comment: As a speaker of US English (originally Middle Atlantic, now New England), I understand *I have got* to mean the same as *I have*, nothing to do with *obtain* or *receive*, but with possession (expressed informally).  *I have gotten* is the same as *I have obtained*.

Comment: While not an exact answer to the question I would like to point out that there is a common (but flawed) usage that ELL's may run into with *got*, specifically the phrases "**You have got to be joking!**" or "**You have got to be out of your mind!**" For these colloquialisms the phrase "*have got to be*" has a very different meaning -- more along the lines of "*must be*" or even just "*are*" -- and is not an indicator of possession or obtaining. Using such a phrase often indicates *disbelief* or *shock* as well.

Comment: Let's not forget American English 'gotten' meaning 'become', as in 'This has really gotten out of hand' and 'It's gotten really expensive to live in New York City.'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Cambridge History of the English Language, Vol 6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521264790), confirming what Barrie England wrote in his answer, says:

> In tracing the history of American grammar, it is important to note
>   that in many instances what might seem to have been a change in
>   American English compared with the standard English of Great Britain
>   is in fact no change at all - it is British English that has changed,
>   not American. For example, eighteenth-century speakers of English
>   generally formed the past participle of *get* 'receive' as *gotten*,
>   as in *Your brother has gotten my mail*. In the nineteenth century,
>   prestigious speakers in England began to drop the -en ending: *Your
>   brother has got my mail*. Most Americans, however, continued using the
>   older form *gotten*.

Answer (score 2):

*Has gotten, have gotten* and *had gotten* are found in American English, but they are not normally used in British English, which prefers *has got*, *have got* and *had got*.

Comment: The word *gotten* exists in British English only in the set phrase *ill-gotten gains*, where it is a fossil.

Answer (score 2):

The terms *have got* and *have gotten* are used differently in American English. Additionally, while (as I understand it) *have* and *have got* are used the same in British English, they are typically used differently in American English.

- *have* is used for actually having something
- *have got* is typically used as equivalant to *have* + already; additionally, the *have* is usually contracted with the subject
- *have gotten* is typically used for having acheived/obtained something in the past, and doesn't always guarantee currently having it

Examples:

> I **have** a cat.

> A: When are you going to get a cat?
>   B: I​**'ve got** one.
>   B (alternate): I **have** one **already**.

> A:**Have** you **gotten** a cat yet?
>   B: I​**'ve gotten** three since we last spoke!

Comment: *B: I​'ve gotten three since we last spoke!* but the dog thought they were delicious so I no longer have any.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that "have got" is more used to represent something that you have possessed for a while, where "have gotten" would mean something more recent.

To be honest, I rarely hear "have got". I think something like "I got" is more often used.

I'm not a teacher, that's my experience speaking English in a daily basis.

Comment: *Au contraire* ... We use "have got" all the time, just normally in the form of a contraction with the subject: I've got the money. / He's got the flu. / They've got the plans. / We've got the time. / You've got mail.