# Do Canadians and Americans really use "gotten" as past participle when speaking?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, past-participles, canadian-english

The OALD has the following note about *get*:

> In spoken North American English the past participle got•ten /ˈɡɒtn/ /ˈɡɑːtn/ is almost always used.

I know that *I have got a car* just means *I have a car*. Excluding that case, do Canadians and Americans really use *gotten* as past participle when speaking? Does that mean they use *got* as past participle when writing, but *gotten* when speaking?

Notice that the OALD reports *got* as past tense, and past participle of *get*. This, and the sentence I previously shown makes me assume the dictionary is saying that *gotten* is used in spoken English from Canadians and Americans, while *got* is used from Canadians and Americans when writing.

I remember that an American friend of mine (born and raised in the East coast) told me I should write *have got*, not *have gotten*.

Comment: Aside: only 1/3 of entries in COCA are spoken.

Comment: Yes, we do. It sounds really weird to us when people from the U.K. say "have got" instead of "have gotten". And we don't use "have got" when we're writing, either. (There are some situations besides possession where you can use "have got" in AmE. For example, you have got to use it when it means "must". I also remember there was some other usage where both "have got" and "have gotten" sounded okay to me, but I have forgotten it.)

Comment: Whoops. Only noticed after I posted an answer, but in the 'related' sidebar on this page it shows that you already asked this question back in January: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/822/gotten-versus-got?rq=1 So I'm going to close this as a duplicate now. If you feel it's not a duplicate and want it reopened please feel free to @ message me and we can sort it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @WendiKidd This is a different question. I am asking about a note found in a dictionary that leads me to think that _have got_ is used in written North American English, while _have gotten_ is used when speaking. The other question is not about spoken North American English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ahh, I see. My apologies, I didn't notice the distinction. Reopening, and I'll edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: Yes. In AE *I have got*, written or spoken, is present tense and means *I possess*, not *I obtain*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, we do.  You're correct that in British English *have got* is what's used, but at least in American English, we do say *have gotten*.

> I've gotten 10 parking tickets already this year!
>
> I have gotten almost no sleep since my baby was born.

In American English we use *have gotten* both when writing and when speaking.  As Peter Shor notes, it sounds very odd to us to hear Brits say (or write) *have got*!

You might also be interested in [this question on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten) which asks about the difference between the two constructions and has some interesting answers.

Comment: It's worth noting, I think, that most americans recognize this (often unconciously) as informal language and when writing or publicly speaking, will manuever around it to avoid both *gotten* (too informal) and *got* (to odd/stilted). So, ending up with sentences more like "*I have received 10 parking tickets this year.*", or "I have had almost no sleep since my baby was born.*"

Comment: It's important to note that we use both got and gotten to mean two different things.  As WendiKidd observes, it would be normal for me to say, *I've gotten ten parking tickets already this year*, to mean I have received ten tickets.   It would also be normal for me to say *I've got two tickets for the theater tonight*, to mean I *possess* two tickets.  The emphasis in the latter sentence is that I have them in my possession, not that I received them.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE writing, almost any form you can imagine is used, depending on style, context, and whether it appears in a quote or not. In speaking, we might say "I got" for past, and "I have gotten" for the past participle, and we generally do not say "I have got" for the past participle. In AmE, "I have got" is indeed used as the present tense (yes, it's somewhat redundant, but at least it's usually contracted to "I've got").

Note that there is another use of this construction. If we were to talk about "getting tired," the past participle would definitely be "I've gotten tired," never "I've got tired," whether in speaking or writing. Admittedly, this is an unusual construction in AmE; we would usually say "I'm tired." (This usage applies to all adjectives in place of "tired," such as "old," "heavy," "exhausted," "drunk," and so on.)

Comment: I wonder for what reason the downvote. The first paragraph says, in general, the same as the other answer. So, it can only be about the second paragraph. Now I'm interested in what is wrong because as a non-native I can't figure out.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I imagine the down-voter voted because the OP wrote, "and 'I have gotten' for the past participle"; that is not the past participle, but the present perfect of _get_.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is confusing. You do explain things better later, but the downvoter might have only read one sentence.

Answer (score -2):

The use of past tenses ending in -en can occur in British English, in some northern dialect.

Example: Pupil to teacher, about another students work

"Tommy's putten 'putten' where he should have putten 'put'"

Comment: Which Northern Dialects are these? I've never heard it in Yorkshire, Cumbria, Lancashire, Manchester or Liverpool, which covers the majority! Somewhere in the deep, dark North-East I assume?

Comment: This is incorrect. They're not saying 'putten'; rather, it's an accented pronunciation of 'putting'. In the present tense, it's simply 'put'.